# iptables rules on squid proxy machine

Tags: iptables, proxy, squid

I use my web-browser to connect to the internet via a squid proxy server (which I own). The proxy port is 3128. I want to lock down the other ports on the machine running the proxy server, however my `iptables` rules are killing the proxy completely. The following rules DO work:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
# other rules here for web access, dns, etc
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s "$my_pc_ip" -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d "$my_pc_ip" -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But obviously, no ports are specified here, so this does not achieve the goal. However when I specify in the proxy port then I am unable to access the internet via the proxy from the web-browser:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
# other rules here for web access, dns, etc
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s "$my_pc_ip" --sport 3128 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d "$my_pc_ip" --dport 3128 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Why are the second set of rules not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have used sport instead of dport and vice versa in the firewall rules.
It should be:

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s "$my_pc_ip" --dport 3128 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d "$my_pc_ip" --sport 3128 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

Since the rules are on your proxy server, in INPUT chain the packets match should be with dport , i.e., the port on which your proxy is running and similarly in OUTPUT chain it should match with sport from where the packets are originating.

Comment: right you are. i could swear i tried this, but i must not have, since it is working now :)